# GCP Cloud functions health check failing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a function in GCP for 2 days and receive the following error each time.

**OperationError: code=13, message=Function deployment failed due to a health check failure. This usually indicates that your code was built successfully but failed during test execution. Examine the logs to determine the cause. Try deploying again in a few minutes if it appears to be transient.**

The Log viewer doesn't give a proper explanation of the problem. Giving the following logs continuously until the deployment fails.

**"Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. The function cannot be initialized."**

Now, the interesting fact is that the same code was working couple of weeks ago.

This issue really makes me wonder that it is a bug from GCP after the recent cloud function upgrade.

Comment: Can you share minimal piece of code? too few information to help you

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue. I found out part of the issue might be related to a dependency issue. In my specific case, related to the slackclient library, but it seems to come from the yarl library and the recommended fix is to define it as `yarl==1.4.2`

Reference:
https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/issues/764

Comment: Thanks, was facing the same issue just now.

Comment: Same for me. It got fixed by adding yarl==1.4.2 in requirements.txt
However I could not find this package when I the ran pipdeptree command. So not sure why this worked.